# Python GNUPG & Docker Container - gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, docker, gnupg

I can encrypt files perfectly fine when specifying a passphrase, but for some reason when I don't specify a password, python-gnupg returns with:

*gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device*

I use a docker container for encrypting and decrypting.

I came across this Github issue (https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/2798), which suggests to run:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

I've added this to my Dockerfile, but I'm still running into the same issue:

```
RUN export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

I couldn't find anything related to *--no-tty* in the docs (https://gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Any help with this would be appreciated!